# How can I override bad EDID with a xorg.conf?

Tags: release-freya, display, graphics, window-manager

So I am using the default opensource Radeon driver, and pretty much every desktop environment (unity, mate, xfce, etc.) is being supplied a bad EDID from my Samsung LN52B750 television. Specifically the physical size is being returned as 7.2" (160x90mm), however it should be more like 52" (880x500mm), everything else seems to be in order though.

Now unlike the aforementioned desktop environments, which seem to scale appropriately, Elementary OS's pantheon is gigantisizing everything to the point where I can't open most windows without having them cutoff by the bottom of the screen.

Are there any xorg experts out there, that can help me out? Please note that this only happens when connected via HDMI, via VGA everything seems okay, however VGA is not an option for me, as I need the HDMI for audio too.

I tried dumping the raw EDID from the VGA, and using it for HDMI, but my xorg.0.log shows a line stating it's not going to use the CustomEDID option... so I'm at a bit of a loss.